# How to implement conditional ordering?

Tags: cakephp, orm, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

i am trying to found out how to create custom order function in cakephp3 order function in ORM find() method.

Let's suppose i have following model

```
User
  name
  ...
  custom_data

custom_data
   type
```

every user has one custom data, where type is one of [ 20, 30, 40 ].

I need order by this type in following manner

```
if ( type == 20 ) {
    // put in first positions
} else {
   // put this records after users with custom_data->type != 20 
}
```

I need to use it in paginator so i need somehing like

```
$this->Users
   ->find()
   ->where([ something ] )
   ->order( 'ASC' => here is my custom function )
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, from your description it sounds as if you need to use `DESC`, given that you say that you want records that match the condition first. In ascending order these records would come last.

That being said, the most simple way would be to use a basic condition, ie SQL wise something like:

```sql
ORDER BY type = 20 DESC
```

It could also be solved using a `CASE` statement, but it's not really neccessary if you have such simple requirements.

```
$query = $this->Users->find();
$query
    ->where(/* .. */)
    ->orderDesc(
        $query->newExpr()->add(['type' => 20])
    );
```

Further ordering statements can be added via additional calls to `order()`, `orderAsc()`, `orderDesc()`.

See also

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::order()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_order)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::orderAsc()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_orderAsc)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::orderDesc()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_orderDesc)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**